# Mongoose array population

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate

I have created a database with the help of mongoose and am now trying to populate a document with its references. Populating a single-document reference works fine, while populating an array does not.

The models giving me trouble are the following:

**Task**

```
var taskSchema = new Schema({
    _client: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Client', required: true },
    link: { type: String, required: true },
    reqDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    startDate: { type: Date },
    extId: { type: String, required: true },
    results: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Result' }]
});
var Task = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

**Result**

```
var resultSchema = new Schema({
    _task: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Task', required: true },
    _module: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Module', required: true },
    finishDate: { type: Date, required: true },
    result: { type: Object, required: true }
});
var Result = mongoose.model('Result', resultSchema);
```

I am adding results to the database with the following code:

```
let taskPromise = Task.findById(req.params.taskId).exec();
let modulePromise = Module.findOne({ name: req.body.module }).exec();

// Wait for promises to finish
Promise.all([taskPromise, modulePromise])
    .then(values => {
        if (values[1]) {
            // Create new result and add to database
            let result = new Result({
                _task: values[0],
                _module: values[1],
                finishDate: Date.now(),
                result: req.body.result
            });
            result.save();

            res.json({ result: 'success' });
        } else {
            // If findOne does not find a result, it resolves the promise instead of rejecting it
            // Therefore Promise.all is successful and we have to check for errors like this
            res.json({ error: 'The module is invalid' });
        }
        // findById on the other hand rejects a promise when it does not find a result
        // That's why we are catching the error here.
    }).catch(err => res.json({ error: 'The task is invalid' }));
```

Results are added with an API-call, the request is being validated beforehand.

To populate, I am using the following code:

```
Task.findById('587f48ba009932409cf51626')
        .populate('results _client').exec(function(err, task) {
            res.json(task);
        });
```

*Dont mind that there is no error handling, this is just for debugging reasons, as the ID is hardcoded aswell*

The population of `_client` works fine while `results` still is an empty array, even though the database is filled with results for this task.

I have been following the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) for this and do not see any difference in my code so I have no idea what I might be doing wrong.

Thoughts on this are greatly appreciated

E/

I tested using

```
Result.find({_task: task}, function(err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
})
```

to get the results for this tasks works perfectly fine and grants all documents I need. I guess this calls for an issue with the reference in which I still can't find any errors.

Answer (score -1):

```
Task.findById('587f48ba009932409cf51626')
        .populate('_client')
        .populate('results')
        .exec(function(err, task) {
            res.json(task);
        })
```

Comment: Since mongoose 3.6 you do not have to call populate multiple times, this code is basically the same as mine.